# Apply FIlters to excel using java

Tags: java, worksheet

I want to apply filters pragmatically (dynamically) to an excel sheet using Java.

Suppose I have an excel sheet(Person.xlsx) with 8 columns

1) Sno

2) Id

3) Name

4) Age

5) Qualification

6) Gender

7) Weight

8) Height

Manually I am applying filters through opening excel sheet through Microsoft-excel and going to DATA --> Filter

Ex: I can apply filter manually to AGE(lets say 20) column and see all the persons who has age 20.

Now I want to do the same thing in Java, I tried with a logic but those couldn't help me, please find the below logic which is giving error

```
import com.aspose.cells.Workbook;
import com.aspose.cells.Worksheet;
public class ExcelFilter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Person.xlsx");
    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
    worksheet.getAutoFilter().setRange("D1");
    worksheet.getAutoFilter().filter(3, "20");
    workbook.save("Person-output.xls");
    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

Getting `Exception in thread "main" com.aspose.cells.CellsException: Field index is out of range.` for the line `worksheet.getAutoFilter().filter(3, "20");`

Comment: can you show the file with data

Comment: Since your Auto Filter covers 1 column shouldn't the index to `filter()` be 0?. `worksheet.getAutoFilter().filter(0, "20");`